# R CMD Check warning: checking S3 generic/method consistency

Tags: r, r-s4

so I am writing a package and have a few generics but am not sure how to solve the warning about S3 consistency.  The manual says that the method arguments must have *all* the arguments of the generic and in the same order.   The generics I've written are all a single argument generics and single argument methods. For brevity, I am only showing the generics which I've written that inherits from a major class.

First Methods for Class-A

```
#' features generic where features is a constructor from SummarizedExperiment clas
#' @name features
#' @rdname features-methods
#' @exportMethod features
setGeneric("features", function(x) standardGeneric("features"))


 #' method for features<-
 #' @name features<-
#' @rdname features-methods
#' @exportMethod features<-
setGeneric("features<-", function(x, value) standardGeneric("features<-"))

#' @rdname features-methods
#' @aliases features
setMethod("features", "KallistoExperiment", function (x) rowRanges(x))
```

Class-B- Methods

setMethod("features", "RangedSummarizedExperiment",
          function (x) rowRanges(x))

```
setReplaceMethod("features", c("RangedSummarizedExperiment", "ANY"), 
             function(x, value) {
               rowRanges(x) <- value
               return(x)
             })
```

So here is what I'm confused about:
1) I am inheriting Class-A methods from SummarizedExperiment.   In fact  my Class-A   is setClass(.... , contains="RangedSummarizedExperiment")    this is how Class-A is defined.  (for more details see arcolombo/arkas  github repository)

There are several other methods, however these other methods are all unique to my custom class-A.  so I'm not sure why S3 inconsistency is being warning (I am following the generic arguments *exactly* )

so the 'features' generic is an accessor of rowRanges. 
  where rowRanges generic is written as

```
## Accessors

 rowRanges(x, ...)
 rowRanges(x, ...) <- value
```

so is the issue that the features generics from Class-A is calling rowRanges(x)  but it should instead call rowRanges(x,...) ?

this warning has got me stuck.

Thank you and good karma to you all.
peace.
kindness.
repeat.

Here is the exact first warning I'm working on:

```
 * checking S3 generic/method consistency ... WARNING
Loading required package: rtracklayer
Loading required package: knitr
Loading required package: stringdist
Loading required package: biomaRt
Warning: replacing previous import ‘Biostrings::tail’ by ‘utils::tail’   when loading ‘TxDbLite’
Warning: replacing previous import ‘Biostrings::head’ by ‘utils::head’ when loading ‘TxDbLite’
  Loading required package: SummarizedExperiment
  Loading required package: Rsamtools
Loading required package: XVector
Loading required package: Biostrings
Loading required package: tools
Loading required package: ComplexHeatmap
Loading required package: grid
Attaching package: ‘ComplexHeatmap’
The following object is masked from ‘package:biomaRt’:
     select
The following object is masked from ‘package:AnnotationDbi’:
    select
Attaching package: ‘arkas’
The following object is masked from ‘package:GenomicFeatures’:
features
See section ‘Generic functions and methods’ in the ‘Writing R
Extensions’ manual.
```

Here is the entire second warning

```
Here is the second warning:

* checking replacement functions ... WARNING
Loading required package: rtracklayer
Loading required package: knitr
Loading required package: stringdist
Loading required package: biomaRt
Warning: replacing previous import ‘Biostrings::tail’ by ‘utils::tail’ when loading ‘TxDbLite’
Warning: replacing previous import ‘Biostrings::head’ by ‘utils::head’ when loading ‘TxDbLite’
Loading required package: SummarizedExperiment
Loading required package: Rsamtools
Loading required package: XVector
Loading required package: Biostrings
Loading required package: tools
Loading required package: ComplexHeatmap
Loading required package: grid
Attaching package: ‘ComplexHeatmap’
The following object is masked from ‘package:biomaRt’:
select
The following object is masked from ‘package:AnnotationDbi’:
select

Attaching package: ‘arkas’
The following object is masked from ‘package:GenomicFeatures’:

features

The argument of a replacement function which corresponds to the right
 hand side must be named ‘value’.
```

Status: 4 WARNINGs, 7 NOTEs
See
  ‘/home/arcolombo/Documents/github_repos/arkas.Rcheck/00check.log’
for details.

I have 4 warnings,  some of them are regarding missing documentations, and usage comments.  these two added detail with replacement methods and generics themselves.

I also get the same warning when I alter the generics to be:

```
setGeneric("features", function(x,...) standardGeneric("features"))


#' method for features<- 
#' @name features<-
#' @rdname features-methods
#' @exportMethod features<-
setGeneric("features<-", function(x,...,value)    standardGeneric("features<-"))

#' @rdname features-methods
#' @param x object with features defined
#' @param ... additional args 
#' @aliases features
setMethod("features", "KallistoExperiment", function (x,...) rowRanges(x,...))
```

(this is adding rowRanges(x,...)  with ...)

perhaps the warning message about head/tails Replace previous import warnings are the culprits?

### Update

So I've tried to reduce some of these masking messages that have arose. after after a bit of cleaning here are the 2 consecutive warnings specifically about generics and methods.

#### Very important note

instead of re-writing the generics above titled features, which called rowRanges.  my class is a child of SummarizedExperiment, which means that my class inherits rowRanges directly.  so I've removed the generics which are built around rowRanges,  and I just use rowRanges directly in my R functions. 
However below is the warning flag.
  I am still not sure the cause of this error.

- checking S3 generic/method consistency ... WARNING
  Loading required package: rtracklayer
  Loading required package: knitr
  Loading required package: stringdist
  Loading required package: SummarizedExperiment
  Loading required package: Rsamtools
  Loading required package: XVector
  Loading required package: Biostrings
  Loading required package: tools
  Loading required package: ComplexHeatmap
  Loading required package: grid

Attaching package: ‘ComplexHeatmap’

The following object is masked from ‘package:AnnotationDbi’:

```
select
```

See section ‘Generic functions and methods’ in the ‘Writing R
Extensions’ manual.
* checking replacement functions ... WARNING
Loading required package: rtracklayer
Loading required package: knitr
Loading required package: stringdist
Loading required package: SummarizedExperiment
Loading required package: Rsamtools
Loading required package: XVector
Loading required package: Biostrings
Loading required package: tools
Loading required package: ComplexHeatmap
Loading required package: grid

Attaching package: ‘ComplexHeatmap’

The following object is masked from ‘package:AnnotationDbi’:

```
select
```

The argument of a replacement function which corresponds to the right
hand side must be named ‘value’.
* checking foreign function calls ... NOTE
Loading required package: rtracklayer
Loading required package: knitr
Loading required package: stringdist
Loading required package: SummarizedExperiment
Loading required package: Rsamtools
Loading required package: XVector
Loading required package: Biostrings
Loading required package: tools
Loading required package: ComplexHeatmap
Loading required package: grid

Attaching package: ‘ComplexHeatmap’

The following object is masked from ‘package:AnnotationDbi’:

```
select
```

See chapter ‘System and foreign language interfaces’ in the ‘Writing R
Extensions’ manual.

Comment: Please add to your question by copying and pasting the exact message that you see.

Comment: I've tried deleting *all* the generics to see if my methods and deleted all my class definitions and rebuilt the package and aftewards reran a check. I still get the same warning.   could masking warning about AnnotationDbi cause this warning?  I do not directly import AnnotationDbi, but import GenmoicFeatures which has AnnotaitonDbi depedencies.

Comment: Are you using a recent version of R (devel, since you're preparing a package for Bioconductor)? Those messages look like the output of a 'normal' package load, mis-interpreted as a warning / error; I have a recollection of that being a problem.

Comment: thank you. I am using R 3.3.1 (not devel) and this should be recent version (?). . I was able to remove this warning by greatly reducing my Depends section to only 1 really needed package.  once I reduced my depends, this warning disappeared.  I received a NOTE regarding the Depends section: * checking package dependencies ... NOTE
Depends: includes the non-default packages:
  ‘edgeR’ ‘limma’ ‘TxDbLite’ ‘SummarizedExperiment’ ‘Rsamtools’ ‘tools’
  ‘ComplexHeatmap’... and greatly reduced my depends section, and these two warnings went away.

Comment: when I submit a package do I need to be on R-devel version of the most recent version?  thank you Martin.

Comment: Sorry, it should not be R-devel for the current release, but the most recent released version of R -- 3.3.1. When I first build and then check (the product of the build process) your package with `$ R --version|head -n1
R version 3.3.1 Patched (2016-08-09 r71069) -- "Bug in Your Hair"`
 I don't see the problem: `* checking S3 generic/method consistency ... OK
* checking replacement functions ... OK` This is with revision 4c9607b which has several dependencies.